# Send POST data from JSP page to remote PHP server (and get an answer)

Tags: java, php, jsp, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to send some data from a JSP page to a PHP one (which should execute some code and return a success message).
I'm using this java function to make some tests:

```
public String excutePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters)
{
URL url;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
try {
  //Create connection
  url = new URL(targetURL);
  connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
           Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

  connection.setUseCaches (false);
  connection.setDoInput(true);
  connection.setDoOutput(true);

  //Send request
  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
              connection.getOutputStream ());
  wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
  wr.flush ();
  wr.close ();

  //Get Response    
  InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  String line;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
  while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
    response.append('\r');
  }
  rd.close();
  return response.toString();

} catch (Exception e) {

  e.printStackTrace();
  return null;

} finally {

  if(connection != null) {
    connection.disconnect(); 
  }
}
}


String urlParameters =
         "var=" + URLEncoder.encode("varcontent", "UTF-8");
   out.println(excutePost("remoteurl",urlParameters));
```

Now if i run the page i get the response "null" and none of the code in the php page is executed.
Am I doing something wrong? How can I allow the php page to run the code in it?
Isn't a simple `echo $_POST['var']` enough to send the data back to the jsp page?

EDIT: I tried to see if the php page is receiving something by writing the posted variable in a file. But nothing is written in it.

```
$file = 'debug.txt';
echo file_put_contents($file, $_POST['var']);
```

and here is the exception i'm getting..

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Answer (score 0):

No, an `echo` is not enough. Put `$_POST['var']` in say a text file and serve the updated text file (Edit the text file each time you need to keep track of `$_POST['var']`). Alternatively you can put it in some DB and check for changes.

Comment: ok thanks... but i'm pretty sure that the php page is not reached at all by that post data.. any idea on why it's not sending the data?

Comment: Check if it's reaching by putting `$_POST['var']` in a text file and `echo`ing the contents of the text file.

Comment: i tried: `code` $file = 'debug.txt';
echo file_put_contents($file, $_POST['var']); now i'm sure that the post data is not received by the php page. Is there something wrong in the java page?

Comment: Not a JAVA expert, sorry. :(